# How to convert WPF Control to XPS document via FixedDoc

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xps

I am building a test report in XAML that needs to be exported into an XPS file. This is the code I have below, however I'm running into an "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first." error when running `fixedPage.Children.Add(TestReportXAML);`
TestReportXAML is the name of my Grid in the Xaml.cs file

```
FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();

fixedDoc.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(96 * 11, 96 * 8.5); // LANDSCAPE
fixedPage.Width = 11 * 96;
fixedPage.Height = 8.5 * 96;

fixedPage.Children.Add(TestReportXAML);
((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);

XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(pathFileNameXPS, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
XpsDocumentWriter xpsWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDoc);
xpsWriter.Write(fixedDoc);
xpsDoc.Close();
```

Initially I had this set of code that worked, however the problem with this is that my XAML gets saved in portrait mode. I don't know if there's a proper way to make this landscape so I'm trying to use a fixed document to convert the XAML orientation before exporting it to XPS.

```
XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(pathFileNameXPS, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
XpsDocumentWriter xpsWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDoc);
xpsWriter.Write(TestReportXAML);
xpsDoc.Close();
```

I am a new developer and new to XAML/WPF, appreciate if things could be explained in less technical terms. Thanks

Comment: Technically, XAML doesn't have an orientation - it's a text file declaring objects, their properties, and how they are related. I think you must have meant the XPS is in the wrong orientation (I guess, idk what XPS is).

Comment: How is `TestReportXaml` actually defined/loaded? The problem is within this xaml file or how it was loaded, not in the code where you're using it. It must have a parent defined, otherwise you wouldn't get that error. Find that. Debug your program and inspect your object.

Comment: @Steve Hey Steve, yes, I did mean the conversion to XPS is in wrong orientation. XPS is just a file extension like PDF. `TestReportXaml` is defined in the main <Grid> of my Xaml.

My Xaml looks pretty much like this structure:

`<Grid x:Name="TestReportXAML"> 

<Mixture of Menus, Labels, Textboxes and DataGrids> 

</Grid>`

Comment: Ok, so let's see how you initialize the variable TestReportXAML. What is it's type? How do you get that variable?

Comment: @Steve Not sure what you mean by initialize in this scenario but the only two instances where I use `TestReportXAML` is when I bind it to the **Name** property of my grid and when I try to use it in the code of the original post. The type is being recognized as a **Grid**